# Как проверить есть ли фраза в строк php

Tags: php

Проблема следующая. С помощью php мне надо определить, есть ли в строке фраза "собрать минимальный пакет".

Строки которые выводятся в цикле могут содержать другой текст.

Различного рода функции **strpos** и тд работают почему то только для символа, но не работают для слова или фразы.

Можно попробовать регулярное выражение, но мне нужно что бы:

```
$bigString = "Собрать минимальный пакет документов и передать его любым удобным Вам способом";

$needle = "Собрать минимальный пакет";

if(если $needle есть в строке $bigString)
сделать что-то
```

**Обновление**

Обьясните ПОЧЕМУ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `if (preg_match("/$needle/", $bigString)) { ... }`

Comment: *Различного рода функции strpos и тд работают почему то только для символа, но не работают для слова или фразы.* А Вы не упускаете, что позиция начинается с нуля, а ни разу не с единицы? и, получая ноль в показанном примере, не трактуете ли его как FALSE?

Comment: я помню об этом. Не упускаю. Я пробовал использовать функции которые возвращают подстроку а не позицию. В результате для фраз ничего не возвращается, только для 1 символа

Comment: Сравните для Ваших данных: `if(strpos($bigString,$needle))` и `if(strpos(' '.$bigString,$needle))`... См. [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cec5d0b5bc90f69c59503d6854cd46d893189718).

Comment: Я не пойму тут все на скорость ответы дают? Я задал конкретный вопрос который надо прочитать внимательно. Я прекрасно могу сравнивать результат и не хочу сейчас вести об этом диалог. У меня вопрос в том как найти фразу в строке. Все варианты strpos и прочие функции успешно работают для 1 слова!!!! Мне надо найти целую фразу, которая имеет пробелы и несколько слов!!

Comment: Я русским по белому показываю - работает поиск по фразе **из трёх слов**. Открой fiddle и запусти код на выполнение. Можешь там же поиграться и исходной фразой, и искомой.

Comment: PS. Для текста лучше спереди добавлять не пробел, а нечто заведомо в тексте отсутствующее. Например, CHR(0).

Comment: Минус вопросу за плохое оформление: код вставляется текстом, а не картинками. "Я не пойму, вы что на скорость вопросы задаёте?" (С)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону функции **stristr**

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello World!';
if(stristr($string, 'earth') === FALSE) {
    echo '"earth" не найдена в строке';
 }
 // выводит: "earth" не найдена в строке
```

Comment: я та пробовал! не работает. еще раз повторяю я ищу не слово! я ищу ФРАЗУ. Представленный вариант работате для 1 слова.

Comment: Вариант работает для вашего примера. Возвращает исходную строку, в случае, если есть сопадения, иначе - false.
$bigString = "Собрать минимальный пакет документов и передать его любым удобным Вам способом";
        $needle = "Собрать минимальный пакет";
        print_r(stristr($bigString, $needle)); - возвращает $bigString.
    $bigString = "Собрать минимальный пакет документов и передать его любым удобным Вам способом";
        $needle = "Test";
        print_r(stristr($bigString, $needle)); - возвращает false

Comment: Не могу понять. На два слова возвращает результат, на три нет. Почему так? Фразу "Собрать минимальный пакет" возвращает фолс, на "Собрать минимальный" тру

Comment: В данный момент проверяю. Как и "Собрать минимальный пакет", так и "Собрать минимальный " так и "Собрать минимальный" - возвращает исходную строку ( то бишь истинну)

Comment: Обновил вопрос скринами. Обьясните почему у меня такая магия

Comment: Покажите в цикле через var_dump() значение, возвращаемое функцией. Так же можете попробовать mb_stristr

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

Стоит почитать про регулярные выражения. Там всё просто, если почитать)

```
$text = "В этом тексте есть нужное слово";
```

Ищем "слово"

```
preg_match("/слово/", $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Вариант 2:

Можно воспользоваться функцией strpos

```
if (strpos($text, 'слово') !== false) // именно через жесткое сравнение
{
    echo 'Найдено';
} else {
    echo 'Не найдено';
}
```